# nusoap basic authentication work on local server but not online

Tags: php, session, authentication, basic-authentication, nusoap

I am developing a simple web service using Nusoap and having problem when adding authentication. The authentication actually work perfect in localhost but not on a remote server. This is what I have so far. I had to figure nusoap out in 3 days so please help if possible.

```
require_once 'nusoap.php';
function doAuthenticate() {
    if (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) and isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])) {
        if ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] == "usr_name" && $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] == "123")
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Client:

```
$client->setCredentials("codezone4", "123", "basic"); 
$result = "";
```

The function calls a simple zip code. In localhost from Client:
[Localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFRbX.jpg)

but as soon as I upload the service to http:systems.com for example it doesn't authenticate.

[Domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwoEm.jpg)

When I call the service in SoapUI from localhost it work when i add basic authentication. however calling the same service from online I get: Invalid username or password

Comment: Good ole nusoap... What differs?  Use of SSL on production?  SSL certificate is valid?  Something hardcoded in WSDL to work on local server but not remote?  Tried turning on trace/exception with soap client / curl?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response ficuscr. Nothing is hard coded. The production server is over SSL and the cert is valid. I initially thought that it might be because of https but also uploaded the service on http and the same result.